# Yii2 Relation of relation sort and search

Tags: sorting, yii2

I have a problem with relational searching and sorting in Yii2.

I am able to sort and search with a single level relation.

Say i have this structure:

Property ->HAS_MANY-> Key_Sets ->HAS_MANY-> Keys

Reverse:

Keys ->HAS_ONE-> Key_Sets ->HAS_ONE-> Property

Within the keys gridview i would like to sort and search by Property

I can search and sort by Key_Sets but not the second level relation

I hope this makes sense

Regards

Liam

Update

In Keys I have

```
public function getKeySet() 
{
    return $this->hasOne(KeySets::className(), ['id' => 'key_set_id']);
}
```

and then

```
public function getProperty()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Properties::className(), 'id', 'key_set_id')->via('keySet');
}
```

This returns

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

```
        if (strpos($parentAlias, '{{') === false) {
            $parentAlias = '{{' . $parentAlias . '}}';
        }
        if (strpos($childAlias, '{{') === false) {
            $childAlias = '{{' . $childAlias . '}}';
        }

        $on = [];
        foreach ($child->link as $childColumn => $parentColumn) {
            $on[] = "$parentAlias.[[$parentColumn]] = $childAlias.[[$childColumn]]";
        }
        $on = implode(' AND ', $on);
        if (!empty($child->on)) {
            $on = ['and', $on, $child->on];
        }
    } else {
        $on = $child->on;
    }
```

With the amazing help of Yupik i have the solution

```
public function getProperty()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Properties::className(), ['id' => 'property_id'])->via('keySet');
}
```

Comment: I have created the normal join in the search model using the join
$query->joinWith(['properties']);
public function getProperties()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Properties::className(), ['id' => 'property_id']);
}
I can then search and sort with a few other modifications in the search model

Comment: But why u cant search or sort on second level? Update your question and paste `search` method.

Comment: First thing is i need to be able to create the relation so the search model can work from there, i just dont know how to create a relation to another relation

Comment: Use method `via()` from ActiveRecord. Link: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activerelationtrait.html#via()-detail

Comment: You are a star, this look like the perfect way forward, I will reply shortly with update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method `via()` or `viaTable()` specifies the relation associated with the junction table.

```
class Order extends ActiveRecord
{
   public function getOrderItems() {
       return $this->hasMany(OrderItem::className(), ['order_id' => 'id']);
   }

   public function getItems() {
       return $this->hasMany(Item::className(), ['id' => 'item_id'])
                   ->via('orderItems');   // here's the magic
   }
}
```

Docs link: [Yii2 ActiveRelationTrait](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activerelationtrait.html#via()-detail)

Comment: How would you do the reverse of this

Comment: In the same way, in `Item` class create `getOrderItems()` and then `getOrder()` by `via()`

Comment: @Liam i see, in `getProperty()` u forgot about `[]`, replace `'id', 'key_set_id'` to `['id' => 'key_set_id']`.

Comment: Many Thanks - You are a star i have been working on this for ages